# Question about Planck's constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-constants

1. How did Dirac or whoever came up with it know that the momentum operator in quantum mechanics is $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$?
2. How did he know the $\hbar$ was in there?
3. How did all these physicists know they had to put $\hbar$?
4. Does it go back to Planck's paper on blackbody radiation?
5. I know it is to make the units correct but why couldn't they use another constant with the same units as $\hbar$, like a constant which was a little bigger than $\hbar$?
6. Also I know that $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$ but basically I am asking why $h$ and not some other constant?

Comment: [Planck fit some now-famous curve to a blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Equations) and required a value of $4.135\,\times10^{-15}\rm{ eV\cdot s}$ for the curve to work.

Comment: Yes I understand that. but how did physicists know that this constant was the one they should use in their formulas. How did they know that this constant related to blackbodies would be the one to use? Does h come up in a lagrangian or hamiltonian in quantum mechanics or physics at the atomic level?

Comment: Have you opened up an introductory textbook on quantum mechanics? Because this *should* be Chapter 1 of any worthwhile book.

Comment: I have intro to QM by david griffiths and it doesn't seem to explain this in the 1st chapter.

Comment: See ["Derivation of quantum mechanical momentum operator in position representation"](http://www.hep.upenn.edu/~rreece/docs/notes/derivation_of_quantum_mechanical_momentum_operator_in_position_representation.pdf)

Comment: Since planck's constant is called a constant of action and the action is an integral over time of the lagrangian is planck's constant something equivalent to the classical action on the quantum level?

Comment: It's a constant "of action" because it has units of action ($\text{energy}\cdot\text{time}$).

Comment: And ($\text{momentum}\cdot\text{distance}$). Go and look at some [pictures of the electromagnetic spectrum](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=electromagnetic+spectrum&biw=1366&bih=651&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI8oKtj8H4xgIVxj0UCh092wqQ). What's always the same regardless of wavelength?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This is a *brief* summary.**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Origin_from_De_Broglie_plane_waves) is helpful, if you can't look anywhere else at the moment. It notes that
$$\hat{p}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
because of the [de Broglie relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#de_Broglie_relations),
$$p=\hbar k$$
where $p$ is momentum and $k$ is the wave vector.

de Broglie's equations, in turn, relate to the de Broglie wavelength,
$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$$
which follows from a variant of the [Planck relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation).

That's the very, very, very, very basic way to look at it. A proper treatment would, of course, be found in a proper textbook on the subject.